# Using Coloured Dots for References

Tags: cross-referencing, color

I'm writing a document which contains multiple copied entries of several online dictionaries. In order to make the references simple enough, I thought of assigning each dictionary a colour and to put a coloured dot at the right of the term whose definition is going to be copied from the dictionary with that coloured dot.

I don't care if instead of a dot it is a square or something. The important thing is that it must be quite visible. Do I use pictures? Is there a square character for doing this? What is the best way to go?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). The following [document](www.cs.rice.edu/~sfogarty/symbols-letter.pdf) contains some commands for shapes you're looking for.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen - A somewhat more up-to-date version (vintage 2009 vs. 2001...) of the document that lists just about all LaTeX symbol may be found at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. For some reason I didn't manage to copy a URL that wasn't poisoned by google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be always a `tikz` answer for such things. But, for a change, you may use `amssymb` symbols for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\mysquare}[1][black]{\small\textcolor{#1}{\ensuremath\blacksquare}}
\newcommand{\mycirc}[1][black]{\Large\textcolor{#1}{\ensuremath\bullet}}
\newcommand{\mylozenge}[1][black]{\small\textcolor{#1}{\ensuremath\blacklozenge}}
\newcommand{\mytriangle}[1][black]{\small\textcolor{#1}{\ensuremath\blacktriangle}}
\newcommand{\mydtriangle}[1][black]{\small\textcolor{#1}{\ensuremath\blacktriangledown}}
\newcommand{\mystar}[1][black]{\Large\textcolor{#1}{\ensuremath\star}} %% or \bigstar
%%Syntax
%\mysquare[<color>]
%\mysquare alone will produce black square. Similarly for circ
\begin{document}

\mysquare[green] \mysquare[olive] \mysquare

\mycirc[green] \mycirc[magenta] \mycirc

\mylozenge[green] \mylozenge[magenta] \mylozenge

\mytriangle[green] \mytriangle[magenta] \mytriangle

\mydtriangle[green] \mydtriangle[magenta] \mydtriangle

\mystar[green] \mystar[magenta] \mystar
\end{document}
```

[image]